# what is the "ant" equivalent for shell command "basename" to get the last dir name in a path

Tags: shell, unix, ant

I am working on an ant script and I have a property set to:

```
 MW_HOME=/path/to/scripts
```

In shell, I can just use below command to get the base directory name i.e. "scripts" in this case ->

```
 dir_name=$(basename $MW_HOME)
```

Is there any such handy command in ant or do I need to process that property to filter out the same? Any suggestion to make it easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html is the equivalent command in ant.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html is a similar command.

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix!